# advice on datastructure for ajax/javascript/jquery page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

This is a JavaScript/Ajax webpage (also using jQuery).

I have a nested structure I need to display. After displaying a top level element, users can click on it, and see levels below it (dynamically generated).

I don't want to pre-generate everything and hide it with display: none (the page is complex, I'm simplifying for this question) - I want to build the display from the javascript array that was fetched with ajax.

My question:

I have two options:

1: Create a flat array:

```
[ {id: xx, children: [ xx, xx, .. ] }, ....]
```

Then for the onclick of an element I get the id from the array, find the children, pull them up from the array and display them. (I guess I'll have to search through the array, since there are no associative arrays in javascript - or make an index.)

2: Create a nested array:

```
{ id: xx, children [ { id: xx, children : [....] }, {....} ] }
```

Then somehow bind the children in the array to the element when I display it.

I have two problems with this second approach:

A: I'm constantly copying large chunks of the array for each child when I create it. (At least I think I am. Do I need to use deep copy? Can I make a reference?)

B: I'm not sure how to bind the data to the child element. Normally I build the display using html strings with onClicks, then append the entire thing. But onClicks can only take an ID, not a copy of an array.

Comment: Would it be possible to build (pre-display) this structure inside a hidden element in the DOM rather than storing a complex piece of data like this?

Comment: The layout varies depending on the order of clicks, so it would be hard to pre-render it.

Comment: If anyone sees this question: Do not use option 2. I did (at first) and it's a nightmare. You have to carry state all the way through every single function that might possibly call another function. Make a flat list using a single identifier, and pass just that identifier in your functions. Make sure you can find a parent from a child (doubly linked). I eventually had to spend a lot of time refactoring everything because the code had become unmanageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar recently where I had a very large nested structure (over 2000 nodes) - which I did not want to bulk append to the DOM.

What I ended up doing was taking the ajax loaded data and converting it into a nested structure...

> ```
> <node id="1" title="a">
>   <node id="2" title="b />
>   <node id="3" title="b">
>       <node id="4" title="d" />
>   </node>
> </node> etc...
> ```

...and storing this as a jQuery object (nodes), but never appending it to the DOM.

I could then select the immediate children of a node as I needed them relatively easily, for converting into html elements and appending to the DOM, adding data, etc...

```
$("#"+ID+">node", nodes).each(function() { 
    var node = $(this);
    //do whatever... 
});
```

I don't know if this is the most memory-efficient approach, but it certainly makes it very easy to select and append the immediate children of a node to the DOM as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the second approach, for the reason it has a better structure as well as you can write less code as recursive comes into play.

You say that your not sure how to bind the child elements to the array without actually creating dom elements, well if you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` for html you elements can have `html-*` attributes allowing you to store data in an element, example:

```
<ul id="lists">
    <li class="parent" id="root_22" data-children="{some object}">A Root Elelment</li>
</ul>
```

the problem with this method is that you would have to store every children of children in the root element, which more than likely is a overhead.

Another way is to bind the data using jQuery.data method, this will keep the DOM clean but will atatch data to an element.

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element.

@see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/